Significance of Shani Pradosha
Pradosha vrata and puja on trayodashi day is auspicious and performed at Shiva temples. However, this puja on Saturdays are performed as Shani Pradosha and with much more grandeur.
What is the significance of Shani Pradosha puja--pradosha on Saturdays?

I) Your first question Pradosha vrata and puja on trayodashi day is auspicious and performed at Shiva temples.
Skanda Purana {Section 3 - Brāhmottara-khaṇḍa, Chapter 6] says about the Importance of Pradoṣa as follows:
The sages said:


0 Sūta, the legend that has been narrated by you is great and
wonderful. It shows the greatness of Śaṃbhu and is destructive of all
sins. We wish to hear it once again, with more mental alertness and
attention.॥ 1-2 ॥

What power does Lord Śaṃbhu grant on being adored at Pradoṣa time by
great souls. O virtuous one, speak this to us. Though oft heard by us,
O Sūta, our desire goes on increasing.॥3॥



Rishi Sūta says about Pradosa and its benefits in slokas [4-14]:


Well asked by you, O highly wise ones, you are well-known all over the world. Hence I shall narrate fully the great merit accruing from
Śiva’s worship.॥ 4 ॥

The dusk on the thirteenth lunar day [triodasi tithi] is called Pradoṣa. The Great Lord and none else should be worshipped then by those who seek benefits.॥ 5 ॥

Who is competent to describe the greatness of the worship at the time of Pradoṣa? It is at that time that: all the Devas stay near
Giriśa (Śiva).॥ 6 ॥

At the time of Pradoṣa, the Lord in his silver abode of Kailāsa, performs dances even as he is eulogized by the Devas revealing his
good qualities.॥ 7 ॥

Hence, Pūjā (worship), Japa, Homa, narration of his stories and eulogies of his good qualities should invariably be carried on by men
desirous of the four benefits (viz. that of virtue, wealth, love and
liberation).॥ 8 ॥

It is the holy raft that shows the other bank (of the ocean of Saṃsāra) to those who get sunk in the ocean of worldly existence, to
the men blinded by the darkness of penury and afraid of mundane
existence (and worries).॥ 9 ॥

To those who are distressed due to misery, grief and fear, to those who wish for the annihilation of all troubles, the worship of
the Lord of Pārvatī at the time of Pradoṣa is the way to prosperity.॥ 10 ॥

Even an evil-intentioned mean fellow, a man deficient in luck, or even a rogue becomes free from adversities by worshipping the Lord of
Devas.॥ 11 ॥

One who is being struck down by enemies, bitten by serpents,
assailed by mountains, fallen into the great ocean, one who is struck
with Kāla’s baton, attacked by many diseases simultaneously: none of
these men becomes destroyed, if he worships Giriśa at the time of
Pradoṣa. ॥ 12-13 ॥

By worshipping Śiva, one shakes off poverty, death, misery, and the weight of debts amounting to a huge mountain and is honoured with
riches.॥ 14 ॥



Beware-1: This is a popular Pradosha Mahatmyam [Shiva Puranam: eight slokas] used to chant on the occasion of pradosa.
A Legend says that the devas (celestial deities) approached Shiva in the most propitious moments of pradosha to get relief from the asuras - Danavas and Daityas. They ran around Kailasha, Shiva's abode hitherto on a Thrayodashi evening and were aided by Nandi, Shiva's sacred bull. Shiva aided them in killing the asuras, which is why the practice of worshipping Shiva on Thrayodashi along with Nandi emerged and continues in Shiva temples.
II) Your second and final question However, this puja on Saturdays are performed as Shani Pradosha and with much more grandeur.What is the significance of Shani Pradosha puja--pradosha on Saturdays?.
The reason for celebration of Pradosa in general (on a triodasi tithi at dusk) and Shani-Pradosa in particularly, lies in the incident of Samudra Manthan(समुद्रमन्थन/Churning of the Ocean) as described in Srimad Bhāgavatam [conto-5, chapter-7] which says that when the devas and asuras were churning the Ocean of Milk in order to get Amrita, the nectar of immortality, the Mandara Parvata (मन्दर पर्वत/Mount Mandara) they were using as the churning shaft started to sink and Vishna took Kūrma Avatara (कूर्म अवतार/A Giant Form of Tortoise), which was 2nd avatar in Krita Yuga (कृतयुग), to bear the weight of the mountain [sloka-9].

The churning of the ocean that agitated all kinds of fish, sharks,
snakes, tortoises, whales, water elephants, crocodiles and
timingilas [whale-eating whales], first of all produced a very
strong poison called Hâlahala [or Kâlakûtha]. ॥ 18 ॥
The terribly strong, unbearable poison, that unstoppably spread
itself in all directions upwards and downwards, scared all the
people such that they, missing the protection of their Lord and
Master, oh my best, sought the shelter of Lord Shiva. ॥ 19 ॥
When they saw him, who for the welfare of the three worlds together
with his wife sits on his mountain [Kailâsa], he, the best of the
demigods served by saints who in austerity walk the path of
liberation, they offered him their obeisances.॥ 20 ॥
The lords of the created beings [the Prajâpatis] said: 'Oh Lord of
Lords, oh Mahâdeva, oh soul of each, oh love of all, deliver us, who
took shelter at your lotus feet, from this poison burning the three
worlds.॥21॥
You are the one lord and master over bondage and liberation in the
entire universe. You, whom we worship, are the spiritual master
capable of taking away the pain of the surrendered followers. ॥ 22 ॥
Mahâdeva out of compassion for the welfare of all living beings
consequently took the widespread Hâlahala poison in his hand and
drank it. ॥ 42 ॥
That poison from the water exhibited its potency by turning his
neck dark-blue, a feature considered an ornament by the virtuous
souls, the saints and the sages. ॥ 43 ॥
Scorpions, cobras and other poisonous animals and plants are the
beings that took care of the little bit of poison that was scattered
here and there as he drank from his palm. ॥ 46 ॥

It is general belief that God Shiva saved the worlds from hālahāla on a triodasi tithi at dusk which was a Saturday, thus the shani triodasi day got immense importance.
Beware-2: Shani Pradosha is the pradosha falling on a Saturday, while Soma Pradosha is the pradosha on a Monday. Maha Pradosha is the Pradosha which falls before or on Maha Shivaratri in the Hindu month of Maagha (or in tamil month Maasi).
Beware-3: There is another version for the importance of Sani-pradosa. According to legend, there was a ruler of Ujjain called Chandrasena, who was a pious devotee of Shiva and worshipped him all the time. He was blessed with a celestial gem which could create miracles. Rivals of Ujjain, king Ripudaman and king Singhaditya of the neighboring kingdoms, attacked Ujjain and take over the treasure. The enemy kings chose to attack, and it happened to be a Saturday and Triyodashi. With the help of the powerful demon Dushan, who was blessed by Brahma to be invisible, they plundered the city and attacked all the devotees of Shiva. Upon hearing the pleas of his helpless devotees, Shiva appeared in his Mahakala (form of light) and destroyed the enemies of king Chandrasena. It is believed that people worshipping Shiva on a Shani Pradosha will be free from the fear of death and diseases. They would also be granted worldly treasures.
Beware-4: Pradosha, as the name implies, has two meanings: (1) it literally means removal of sins (Pra + Dosam), and (2) it refers to the Dusk time, also known as the Godhūli (गोधूलि/dust of the cows), the time of sunset or evening twilight, so called because cows, which generally return home at about sunset, raise up clouds of dust by their treading on the earth) i.e. a time period of around 3 hours, divided into 1.5 hours before dusk and 1.5 hours after nightfall (sunset), also knowns as Pradosha Kālam.
